# Bibliography doesn't show up when using amsart with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, amsart, bibliographystyle

I am using Latex in Overleaf to compile a document, but I can't get the bibliography to appear in the document.

I have two files, one called main.tex and one called sample.bib (in sample.bib I have the references in BibTeX format).

I'm using `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}` and for the bibliography `\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}`
`\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`, but these two seem to conflict with each other.

Here is a minimal reproducible example of my .tex file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage[margin=0.8in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,systeme}
   
\date{}

\parskip 0.2cm

\begin{document}

\title[Title bla bla]
{Title bla}

\author{Name$^1$}
\address{$^1$ xxx}
\address{$^2$ xxx}
\address{$^3$ xxx}
\email{xxxxx@x.x}

\subjclass[2010]{xxxx, xxxx.}

\keywords{xxxx $|$ xxxx $|$ xxxx}

\begin{abstract}
Bla bla bla
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Main}
Bla bla bla bla bla \cite{authorname2022}.
 
\section*{Acknowlegements}
bla bla

% Bibliography
\section*{References}
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Here is an example of BibTex reference as appears in my sample.bib:

```
@article{authorname2022,
  title={A model},
  author={xxx, xxxx},
  journal={Nonlinear xxx},
  volume={1},
  number={1},
  pages={1--1},
  year={2020}
}
```

Here is the warning:
[image]

Comment: And what exactly is in`sample.bib`?

Comment: @daleif In sample.bib I have the references in BibTeX format.

Comment: Show what you have, we cannot test your example without it. Your example only needs the  `authorname2022` entry in it.

Comment: Btw: only load packages once, and with a few exceptions `hyperref` should be loaded last. And  `pslatex` should not be used

Comment: Thanks @daleif , I have updated the question by adding an example of BibTex reference. I am now loading `hyperref` last and I deleted `pslatex`. The problem persists.

Comment: This might have to do with the way amsart redefines `\bibliographystyle`. If you want to use unsrtnat,  try putting the line `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}` *after* `\begin{document}`. (You could even put it right before `\bibliography{sample}` if you want.) Also, you don't need `\section*{References}`; that'll be inserted automatically.

Comment: @frabjous voilà, it worked. Thanks. You might want to add the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate what I wrote in the comments, I believe this has to do with the way amsart redefines `\bibliographystyle`; in order to use a bibliography style like unsrtnat, it'll need to be loaded *after* `\begin{document}`. In this case, it could be loaded right before `\bibliographystyle{sample}`.